# How would I implement this query in an SSIS dataflow?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, dataflow

So I have something that I did in an execute SQL task but my project manager would rather see it in a data flow task.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[lookup_product]
       ([dim_global_data_source_id]
       ,[source_product]
       ,[source_product_type]
       ,[source_grade]
       ,[source_gauge]
       ,[source_width]
        )

SELECT distinct 
       dim_global_data_source_id,
       product_desc,
       product_type,
       grade,
       gauge,
       size1

FROM Staging_informix_Coil_is
where not exists 
(select source_product 
 from lookup_product 
 where lookup_product.dim_global_data_source_id  =           Staging_informix_Coil_is.dim_global_data_source_id 
 and isnull(lookup_product.source_product,'') =  isnull(Staging_informix_Coil_is.product_desc,'')
 and lookup_product.source_product_type       = Staging_informix_Coil_is.product_type
 and isnull(lookup_product.source_grade,'')   = isnull(Staging_informix_Coil_is.grade,'')
 and isnull(lookup_product.source_gauge,0)    = isnull(Staging_informix_Coil_is.gauge,0)
 and isnull(lookup_product.source_width,0)    = isnull(Staging_informix_Coil_is.size1,0)
)
```

`

That's the query. I need this in a workflow. Someone help me out or give me a sample

Comment: Where are you stuck at?

Comment: Mentally parsing your query, it seems like you are trying to load data into a table I'd it's not already there. Do you have a requirement to detect changes betwixt source and destination or does a check on the business keys suffice? Bingle Andy Leonard ssis incremental load pattern or look harder through the ssis questions here to find examples

Comment: All the tables exist. I essentially just need to look up my staging table with the lookup.  If the values of the staging table don't exist in the lookup then populate the lookup.  I guess where I'm stuck is how to refer to the lookup and check if records exist or not. Then inserting those records.

Comment: After you implement the lookup solution make sure you take some good metrics on the performance of both methods and present to your project manager if there is anything of note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm with your project manager on this one. I would create a Data Flow Task.  The first component would be an OLE DB Source, containing just your first SELECT (no WHERE clause).

The next component would be a Lookup, selecting the columns you need to match on from lookup_product.  On the Columns tab I would match the columns as you have in your WHERE clause.  On the General tab I would set it to Redirect Rows to No Match output.

The final component is an OLE DB Destination, pointing at the lookup_product table.  I would connect this to the Lookup using the No Match output.